# AS3 - Error 1106, can't use Timer

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm having an issue with my timer. I'd like to make some instances disappear after a timer is finished. However, I am getting error 1106. The error states that the if statement is empty and that there should be code. However, there is code (the quickTimerBegin function.)

```
  import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;

var F20quickTimer:Timer = new Timer(5000,1); 
F20quickTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, quickTimerBegin); 

//checkmarks invisible at start 
F20next_btn.visible=false; 
F20chloroplastCheck_mc.visible=false; 
F20cytoplasmCheck_mc.visible=false; 
F20mitochondriaCheck_mc.visible=false; 
F20golgiCheck_mc.visible=false; 

//allows an instance to be dragged 
//allows an instance to be dropped 
F20chloroplasts_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag); 
F20chloroplasts_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropChloroplast); 
F20cytoplasm_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag); 
F20cytoplasm_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dropCytoplasm); 
F20mitochondria_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag); 
F20mitochondria_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropMitochondria); 
F20golgi_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag); 
F20golgi_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropGolgi);
```

---

ERROR IS HERE

```
**if((F20chloroplasts_mc.visible==true)&&(F20cytoplasmCheck_mc.visible==true)&&(F20mitochondriaCheck_mc.visible==true)&&(F20golgiCheck_mc.visible==true))
{
    function quickTimerBegin(event:TimerEvent):void{
        F20next_btn.visible=true; 
    }
}**
```

---

rest of code

```
//when an instance is clicked on, it will be dragged 
function drag(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
    event.target.startDrag(); 
    F20output_txt.text = ""; 
}

//when baseball_mc hits baseballPlayer_mc, a checkmark will appear 
function dropChloroplast(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
    F20chloroplasts_mc.stopDrag(); 

    if(F20chloroplasts_mc.hitTestObject(F20chloroplastBox))
    {
        F20chloroplastCheck_mc.visible = true; 
        F20chloroplasts_mc.x=356; 
        F20chloroplasts_mc.y=539.45; 
        F20chloroplasts_mc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag); 
    }
    //will return baseball_mc to original position if it does not hit baseballPlayer_mc 
    else 
    {
        F20chloroplasts_mc.x = 618.70; 
        F20chloroplasts_mc.y= 167.75; 
    }
}

//when tennisbal_mc hits tennisPlayer_mc, a checkmark will appear 
function dropCytoplasm(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
    F20cytoplasm_mc.stopDrag(); 

    if(F20cytoplasm_mc.hitTestObject(F20cytoplasmBox))
    {
        F20cytoplasmCheck_mc.visible = true; 
        F20cytoplasm_mc.x=354.25; 
        F20cytoplasm_mc.y=403.20; 
        F20cytoplasm_mc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag); 
    }
    //will return tennisball_mc to original position if it does not hit tennisPlayer_mc 
    else 
    {
        F20cytoplasm_mc.x = 623.65; 
        F20cytoplasm_mc.y= 272.60; 
    }
}

//when soccerball_mc hits soccerPlayer_mc, a checkmark will appear 
function dropMitochondria(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
    F20mitochondria_mc.stopDrag(); 

    if(F20mitochondria_mc.hitTestObject(F20mitochondriaBox))
    {
        F20mitochondriaCheck_mc.visible = true; 
        F20mitochondria_mc.x=357.15; 
        F20mitochondria_mc.y=292.45; 
        F20mitochondria_mc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag); 
    }
    //returns soccerball_mc to original position if it does not hit soccerPlayer_mc 
    else 
    {
        F20mitochondria_mc.x = 621.60; 
        F20mitochondria_mc.y= 394.50; 
    }
}

//when footbal_mc hits footballPlayer_mc, a checkamrk will appear 
function dropGolgi(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
    F20golgi_mc.stopDrag(); 

    if(F20golgi_mc.hitTestObject(F20golgiBox))
    {
        F20golgiCheck_mc.visible = true; 
        F20golgi_mc.x=353.50; 
        F20golgi_mc.y=150; 
        F20golgi_mc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag); 
    }
    //returns footbal_mc to original position if it does not hit footballPlayer_mc 
    else 
    {
        F20golgi_mc.x = 622.85; 
        F20golgi_mc.y= 535.15; 
    } 
}
```

I appreciate all the help!

Comment: What is the point of putting the `quickTimerBegin` function in an if conditional? Just remove the  conditional and keep the function on the same level as all the other functions. If the conditional is necessary, why not move it **inside** the function?

Comment: @DodgerThud  I want the timer to begin ONLY WHEN the conditional has been met though.

Comment: Right now the timer would never start at all because I don't see you actually calling the `start()` function of the timer. To actually solve your problem, you could use an `ENTER_FRAME` event that constantly checks your conditions and starts the timer if it isn't already running. But that's too performance heavy for such a simple task. You could also define setter/getter functions for the visibility states of your mc, and each time the setter gets called, you check the conditions and start the timer when they've been met. I'll try to write a proper answer in the next days, but no promises.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're implementing the function in a wrong way..
It should be like this

```
function quickTimerBegin(event:TimerEvent):void{
    if((F20chloroplasts_mc.visible==true)&&(F20cytoplasmCheck_mc.visible==true)&&(F20mitochondriaCheck_mc.visible==true)&&(F20golgiCheck_mc.visible==true))
    {
        F20next_btn.visible=true; 
    }
}
```

You can control when the timer starts with `F20quickTimer.start()`.
And maybe you want to restart the timer again if the condition was not met with `F20quickTimer.reset()` then start it again.. Or increasing the *repeatCount*..
This would be easy if you know the [documentation](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html#Timer())

Comment: will that allow the timer to begin ONLY WHEN the conditional is met?